# Weird IE issue in jQuery carrousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have a weird jQuery issue, in Safari and Chrome it works fine. I just see 4 columns. But in IE(10) I see 1 column and sometimes 4 columns.. Here is the link: http://bit.ly/IoLmgy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter which browser it is, there is always only 1 column until all pictures are loaded, then layout gets loaded. Press ctrl+f5 and see for yourself. I am not sure how you load your content but make sure your layout loads first and then the pictures.

```
.columns-4 .project-post {
float: left;
height: 250px;
margin: 12px;
width: 207px;
}
```

Try this but remove position: absolute; and transform: translate; on those li's.

Comment: Its loading with a PHP while loop. But thats just "building" the page. What do you recommend?

Comment: Try this, I can't test it all because of php. You might lose some effects without transition.